# express-session deprecated undefined resave option even after explicitly declaring these parameters

Tags: express, passport.js

The below code giving errors as follows:-

```js
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);
```

```
express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option app.js:44:19
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option app.js:44:19
express-session deprecated req.secret; provide secret option app.js:44:19
```